# change font for table and within text

Tags: tables, fonts, amsmath, font-encodings

I have the following table

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand*{\myfont}{\fontfamily{qcr}\selectfont}

\begin{document}
Lorem  {\myfont ipsum}
{\myfont
\begin{table}[h]
\setlength\tabcolsep{1.5pt}
\begin{tabular}{lllllllll}
1   &   2   &   3   &   4   &   5   &   6   &   7   &   8   &   9\\
A,  &   B,  &   C,  &   D,  &   E,  &   F,  &   G,  &   H,  &   I \\
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
}
\end{document}
```

why does 'ipsum' is rendered with `\myfont` but the table doesn't? How can I change the font of the table accordingly?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Move type of font inside `table`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand*{\myfont}{\fontfamily{qcr}\selectfont}

\begin{document}
Lorem  {\myfont ipsum}

\begin{table}[ht]
\myfont
\setlength\tabcolsep{1.5pt}
\begin{tabular}{lllllllll}
1   &   2   &   3   &   4   &   5   &   6   &   7   &   8   &   9\\
A,  &   B,  &   C,  &   D,  &   E,  &   F,  &   G,  &   H,  &   I \\
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]